# Why does the compiler ask for the day,month and year of joining simultaneously?

Tags: c, struct

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 struct personal
{
    char name[20];
    int day;
    char month[12];
    int year;
    float salary;
};
 void main()
{
        struct personal person;/*Name of structure is personal*/
        printf("Enter name of employee");
        scanf("%s",&person.name);
        printf("\nEnter day of joining");
        scanf("%d",&person.day);
        printf("\nEnter month of joining");
        scanf("%s",&person.month);
        printf("\nEnter year of joining");
        scanf("%d",&person.year);
        printf("\nEnter salary of employee");
        scanf("%f",&person.salary);
        printf("\nThe details are as follows\n");
        printf("Name of employee-%s\n",person.name);
              ("Date of joining-%d %s
                     %d\n",person.day,person.month,person.year);
               ("Salary of employee-$%f",person.salary);
     getch();}
```

Is the above code correct?What's the best way to learn structures in C?
How does one combine structures and functions?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that its asking all three at same time because while entering the name of the employee, you are entering "a blank space", but name is a char array and if you use scanf, it will skip other inputs.
So better to use "gets()" function. So the code would look like-

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 struct personal
{
    char name[20];
    int day;
    char month[12];
    int year;
    float salary;
};
 void main()
{
        struct personal person;/*Name of structure is personal*/
        printf("Enter name of employee");
        /*Replace this line - scanf("%s",&person.name); by*/
        gets(person.name);
        printf("\nEnter day of joining");
        scanf("%d",&person.day);
        printf("\nEnter month of joining");
        scanf("%s",&person.month);
        printf("\nEnter year of joining");
        scanf("%d",&person.year);
        printf("\nEnter salary of employee");
        scanf("%f",&person.salary);
        printf("\nThe details are as follows\n");
        printf("Name of employee-%s\n",person.name);
              ("Date of joining-%d %s
                     %d\n",person.day,person.month,person.year);
               ("Salary of employee-$%f",person.salary);
     getch();}
```